# How can I trigger orl event

Tags: jquery, scroll

How can I trigger or execute a class animation with scroll eventHow can I triggerHow can I trigger or execute a class animation with scroll eventHow can I trigger or execute a class animation with scroll eventHow can I trigger or execute a class animation with scroll eventHow can I trigger or execute a class animation with scroll eventHow can I trigger or execute a class animation with scroll eventHow can I trigger or execute a class animation with scroll event
        to
        {
            background-position: -10234px;
        }
    }

```
@keyframes close
{
    from
    {
        background-position: -10234px;

    }
    to
    {
        background-position: 0;
    }
}
```

**JS:**

```
  $(function(){
  $(window).scroll(function(){

    var st = $(this).scrollTop();

    if(st >= 599){
      var element = document.getElementById("myDIV");
          element.classList.remove("close");
          element.classList.add("open");
          element.classList.remove("static");
      console.log('OPEN!');
    }
    else if(st <= 600 && st < 600){
      var element = document.getElementById("myDIV");
      element.classList.remove("open");
      element.classList.add("close");
      element.classList.remove("static");
  console.log('CLOSE!');

    }
    else {

    }
  });
  });
```

Comment: You want to change the behavior depending on whether a user is scrolling up or down? So say if I scroll towards the bottom and reach `599px`, then `element.classList.add("animateOpenScroll");` is invoked (like you're showing). But if the scroll is below `599px` and I scroll towards the top, you want `element.classList.add("animateColseScroll");` to get invoiked? Is that the question?

Comment: Hi seebiscuit!, yes, but in both ways, just update the post so you can see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a very lazy answer on the last day of 2018...Happy New Year ;)

```
$(function(){
  $(window).scroll(function(){

    var st = $(this).scrollTop();

    if(st >= 599 && st < 799){
      var element = document.getElementById("myDIV");
      element.classList.add("animateOpenScroll");
    }
    else if(st >= 799){
       //do whatever you need to do if scroll top reaches (or surpasses) 799
    }
    else {
       //you'll need this. Fall back to the initial state...when scroll top is less than 599
    }
  });
  });
```

#### More Details

The main problem is that your `div` has 2 states, not 3. It is either open or close and then your `if...else` block doesn't reflect this...in fact, it's a bit over the place...for example this...

```
else if(st <= 600 && st < 600){}
```

doesn't make much sense, not to mention the empty `else` block which is essentially the same as the `else if` block in this context. You need to tidy up your code first to make it easier to understand...

#### Tidying Up

The `.static`, `.open` and `.close` css classes are basically the same, the only difference is that the last 2 add an animation. You can easily remove those declarations. Here's your new `.open`, `.close` classess...

```
.open{
    animation: open 0.5s steps(14);
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-play-state: running;
}

.close{
    animation: close 0.5s steps(14);
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-play-state: running;
}
```

now in your `jQuery` code you don't need to add/remove the `.static` css class. Also, you need to get keep track of the state of your div to know when to play the `.close` animation and when not to. 
See all the changes below...

```js
var open = false;

$(function(){
  var element = document.getElementById("myDIV");
  var scrollMarker = 599;
  
  $(window).scroll(function(){

    var st = $(this).scrollTop();

    if(st >= scrollMarker){
      open = true;
      element.classList.remove("close");
      element.classList.add("open");
    }
    
    //plays the close animation only if the "state" of the div is open
    else if(open) {
     open = false;
      element.classList.remove("open");
      element.classList.add("close");

    }
    
  });
  
});
```

```css
body {
    background-color: black;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
    height: 2500px;
}

.static{
    position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: calc(10965px / 15);
  height: 499px;
  background: url(https://www.nvidia.com/content/dam/en-zz/Solutions/titan/titan-rtx/titan-rtx-exploded-view-v022-seq1-15f-ld.jpg);
}

.open{
    animation: open 0.5s steps(14);
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-play-state: running;
}

.close{
    animation: close 0.5s steps(14);
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-play-state: running;
}

@keyframes open
{
    from
    {
        background-position: 0;
    }
    to
    {
        background-position: -10234px;
    }
}


@keyframes close
{
    from
    {
        background-position: -10234px;

    }
    to
    {
        background-position: 0;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myDIV" class="static"></div>
```

You might have to click on "Full Page" if you want to see the animation or...change the value of `scrollMarker`

Comment: Hi Leo!, Happy new year!, thank you so much for the answer, I'm using your suggestion, but now I have a new issue, I just update the post so you can see it better.